# HortonWorks hadoop data security and encryption tools

Tags: hadoop

Can anybody tell me about tools that are available for data security and encryption which are supported by the HortonWorks distribution of hadoop? And also, how to encrypt fully or partially data file in hdfs and hive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP) supports [Apache Knox](http://knox.apache.org/) which is a REST Gateway that provides perimeter security in the form of authentication and access control.  Here is a great Slide Share presentation that describes [how Hortonworks works with Knox](http://www.slideshare.net/vinnies12/hadoop-security-today-tomorrow-apache-knox).

Additionally, the Hortonworks Data Platform version 2.2 brings support for [Apache Ranger](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/ranger/), which is a policy-based security framework for defining policies to control access to files, folders, databases, tables, or columnns.   This works with HDFS, Hive, HBase, Storm as well as Knox.

Hortonworks has an excellent tutorial that brings these concepts together here: http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/manage-security-policy-hive-hbase-knox-ranger/

Note that these capabilities primarily address the issue of access control.  Authentication verifies a claim of identity, and Authorization determines what data authenticated requestors (known in security-speak as "subjects") are allowed to access and what actions they are allowed to perform.

There are additional areas of data security such as securing data at rest (within HDFS) and data-in-transit (being passed between components).  The US healthcare industry, credit card industry, and government each have separate sets of regulations that require the encryption of data both at-rest as well as in-transit.

Here is a link to a section of the Apache Hadoop 2.5.0 documentation that describes how to run [Hadoop in Secure Mode](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#Hadoop_in_Secure_Mode).  Specifically this addresses ways to secure Hadoop ***data-in-transit*** by encrypting data in RPC requests, data in block read and write requests, and data being transferred between the web console and clients.

The issue of securing ***data-at-rest*** is addressed by JIRA [HDFS-6134](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6134) which we should expect to see with Hadoop release 2.6.0 along with a key management server.

Comment: What About voltage datasecure,dataguiseDG and protegrity,are they tools or add-ons?

Comment: Can you please explain on how the data is encrypted in these tools and waht are the steps?

Comment: These are products from vendors that are Hortonworks partners.  For more details see: http://hortonworks.com/partners/ecosystem/#security.

Comment: please share a link for installation and procedure for Knox and Ranger.